# Bash command to generate random password breaking on macOS Big Sur upgrade

Tags: bash, macos, random, macos-big-sur

I used the following bash command to generate a random password of length 5 previously on macOS Catalina. When I updated to macOS Big Sur, this now displays random non-unicode characters.

```
export LC_CTYPE=C && head /dev/urandom | tr -dc a-z0-9 | head -c5
e1q�y
```

Any idea what needs to be modified?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `bash`? Big Sur changed the default shell to `zsh`, so if you created a new account it will use `zsh`.

Comment: I don't think they changed the version of `bash`. Apple is stuck on an old version of bash because they don't want to conform to the license for more recent versions.

Comment: Tangentially, this command line will override `LC_CTYPE` for the rest of the lifetime of the current shell. Probably you'd want to run this in a subshell to avoid having it mess with your locale settings more generally.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `LC_ALL` set which would override `LC_CTYPE`. To be safe just use `LC_ALL`.

```
$ LC_ALL=C bash -c 'head /dev/urandom | tr -dc a-z0-9 | head -c5'
hr0by
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try below  one line bash script to generate random strong password.

```
cat /dev/urandom |tr -dc "[[:graph:]]" |head -c16;echo
```